# How to redirect %%view_email_url%% when data from DE is deleted

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

I dont know if its possible the redirect to a different page or create a default email.
I've created an email and add the %%view_email_url%% in the body so the person can see it "fresh" because the content is changing, but if the row in the DE is deleted the url will be redirected to something like "The system is temporarily unavailable ...", is there a way to redirect to %%view_email_url%% to something else when the data related to the email is deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easily.

You could set up so that your 'View as Webpage' link goes to a different CloudPage you set up and passes the view_email_url parameter to it (likely using CloudPagesURL function) and then on that page, you do a GET call to the page to see if it returns an error or not, and if it errors, then you change the target URL to whatever default you want, but if it does not, then set the target as that VAWP url.  You then would do a redirect via AMPscript/SSJS to that new URL you set.

This can be fairly complicated and certainly comes with risk.

Your only other option is to have it so that when the email is loaded as VAWP it draws the info from the sendlog or another DE source and not the sendable DE (via lookups) to make it so it will still display even if no longer existing in sendable DE. But this would not provide the most up to date content, only the content from the last send.

There may be some combination of the two you could use, but honestly there is no easy solution that I know of and each comes with risk.